# How to configure web administration module in ejabberd (2.1.x)?

Tags: ejabberd

Hii All Thanks for viewing this issue please help me i am trying to configure ejabberd from last 3 days but still not having any solution i added

these code in ejabberd.cfg

```
{hosts, ["localhost","server.mobulous.in"]}.
{acl, admin, {user, "admin", "server.mobulous.in"}}.
```

---

is this a issue of server port because i install zpanel on my vps server and its running on this ip `http://119.18.63.178/`

So do i need to change server.mobulous.in to this IP?

and also i am not able to access this and this

```
http://119.18.63.178:5280/admin
http://server.mobulous.in:5280/admin
```

Help me please i am new to vps and dont know to much

Thanks in advance

```
[root@server ~]# tail /var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log
I(<0.465.0>:ejabberd_listener:166) : Reusing listening port for 5222

=INFO REPORT==== 2014-03-21 13:27:39 ===
I(<0.466.0>:ejabberd_listener:166) : Reusing listening port for 5269

=INFO REPORT==== 2014-03-21 13:27:39 ===
I(<0.467.0>:ejabberd_listener:166) : Reusing listening port for 5280

=INFO REPORT==== 2014-03-21 13:27:39 ===
I(<0.36.0>:ejabberd_app:72) : ejabberd 2.1.13 is started in the node ejabberd@server
```

Answer (score 3):

### "Hosts" in ejabberd

The `hosts` configuration clause in ejabberd has unfortunate name as it really denotes *XMPP domains* your server hosts, not the name (or IP address) of the machine it's running on.  So if your users will have JIDs of the form `sismaster@server.mobulous.in`, then you only need to have `server.mobulous.in` in the `hosts` clause.

Note that if your XMPP domain is `mobulous.in` you'll have to [properly setup DNS SRV records for your server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22102981/720999) so that records for `mobulous.in` point to `server.mobulous.in`.

### Web administration interface in ejabberd

In order for web administration interface to work on a certain port, the `web_admin` module has to be enabled in the configuration of that port's listener.

For instance, in order to have web admin interface served on 5280 you need to have something like this in your configuration file:

```
{5280, ejabberd_http, [web_admin]},
```

I've recently helped someone on the ejabberd mailing list with the similar problem; you can read my rather extensive message [here](http://lists.jabber.ru/pipermail/ejabberd/2014-March/008262.html).