# XMPP server timeout on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-ec2, erlang, xmpp

I've deployed XMPP server on EC2. I'm experiencing problem with client connection to the server. Server is located in N.California. **I can't establish stable connection with server. I can get connected 3 times in the row, but the 4th time will always be timeout. XMPP server logs show that server doesn't even establish connection with client**

I've used 2 clients (Pidgin, XMPPHP php script). I've used 2 different versions of XMPP servers (eJabberd, MongooseIM with my modifications) same result.

Result of PHP script to connect.

```
1404297313 [INFO]: Connecting to tcp://xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5222
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5222 (Connection timed out) in     /home/ubuntu/xmppphp/XMPPHP/XMLStream.php on line 313
1404297344 [ERROR]: Could not connect.
```

I tried telnet from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101523/how-to-open-ejabberd-server-to-public) according to this post. I have connectivity problem.

```
$ telnet xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 5222
Trying xx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Security group issue is out of the question, because i wouldn't get connected at all.TCP dump doesn't show any packets transferred when connection is timeout.

Am i missing something? I've used this tutorial on [TCP tweaking](http://www.nateware.com/linux-network-tuning-for-2013.html#.U7LBG3WSxhG)  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was fixed by changing port from 5222 to 4000.