# Configuring nginx as a tcp proxy for ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying to configure nginx as a tcp proxy for ejabberd.

The nginx configuration for tcp proxying is as shown below

```
stream{
    upstream ejabberd-servers{
        server ejabberd:5222;
    }
    server{
        listen 5222;
        proxy_pass ejabberd-servers;
    }
}
```

The ejabberd server is the ejabberd server node name. Since this is done in a docker environment.

When I connect to nginx using smack client library, I get the error is SOCKS5 socket fail.

When I try connection using SOCKS4, I get Servers response VN 60

The reason I am trying to do so is because I do not want to expose ejabberd directly to the Internet. I need to have a proxy to load balance connections and also prevent DDos attacks.

Setting up ejabberd for Internet is nicely explained here.
[[how to open ejabberd server to public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101523/how-to-open-ejabberd-server-to-public][1])

Has anybody done so successfully?